# nodejs and socket.io-redis (socket.io 1.0.6): how to redis subscribe?

Tags: node.js, sockets, node-redis, socket.io-1.0

I just updated socket.io to version 1.0.6 and found out that there is no redis under socket.io/node_modules anymore.

So, I npm installed socket.io-redis, as this thread says that it is the correct solution:
[Migrating socket.io from 0.9.x to 1.x, Problems with configuring RedisStore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23952640/migrating-socket-io-from-0-9-x-to-1-x-problems-with-configuring-redisstore/24673390#24673390)

But, with the last version, I used to have the following code on my app.js:

```
var redis = require('socket.io/node_modules/redis');
var sub = redis.createClient();
```

With this new approach, running node app.js raises an error: it complains that redis has no createClient method.

How should I do to subscribe using socket.io (1.0.6) and socket.io-redis?

Answer (score 0):

You should import `redis` module in addition to the `socket.io-redis`.

```
var redisAdapter = require('socket.io-redis');
var redis = require('redis');

var pub = redis.createClient(port, host);
var sub = redis.createClient(port, host);

io.adapter( redisAdapter({pubClient: pub, subClient: sub}) );
```

Comment: Hi Aruna, could you please guide a little further on how can I use these pub and sub object in my code later on ?
Do you have any example code or any reference because looking into docs of 'socket.io-redis' library, i can't have any clear idea.

Comment: Hi Shivam, I haven't used socket.io in over two years. So I only vaguely remember how everything adds up. But if I remember correctly you dont have to use those pub sub clients as they are used internally by the redis adapter. So you don't have to worry about them.

Comment: yeah, thanks a lot. I have figured it out though by looking little bit into library's code.